# How to create auto growing-shrinking input by using React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need an input that will have min width and max width and it will grow and shrink according to its content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have state. It can be passed as a parameter (hoisted state, when a state is at the upper level) or be right in the component
Then just use the length of the input-state

#### New solution

```js
const Input = (props) => {
    const [value, changeValue] = React.useState('');

    return (
        <input
            style={{ width: Math.min(Math.max(value.length, 2), 50) + 'ch' }}
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => {
                changeValue(event.target.value);
            }}
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<Input />);
```

```css
input {
  font-family: "Roboto", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Math.min and Math.Max are used to have size between min(2) and max(20). Without monospace font-family you can get other results

#### Old solution

```js
const {useState} = React;


const Input = (props) => {
    const [value, changeValue] = useState('');
  
    return (
            <input 
        size={Math.min(Math.max(value.length, 2), 20)}
                value={value}
                onChange={(event) => {changeValue(event.target.value);}}
            />
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Input />
);
```

```css
input {
  font-family: "Roboto", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, {
  type CSSProperties,
  type InputHTMLAttributes,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState
} from 'react'

const sizerStyle: CSSProperties = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  visibility: 'hidden',
  height: 0,
  overflow: 'scroll',
  whiteSpace: 'pre'
}
export default function AutosizeInput(props: InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) {
  const originMinWidth = props.style?.minWidth
  const originMaxWidth = props.style?.maxWidth
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  const textRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(1)
  const [refStyle, setRefStyle] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    const s = getComputedStyle(inputRef.current!)
    setRefStyle({
      fontSize: s.fontSize,
      fontFamily: s.fontFamily,
      fontWeight: s.fontWeight,
      fontStyle: s.fontStyle,
      letterSpacing: s.letterSpacing,
      textTransform: s.textTransform
    })
  }, [props.className, props.style])
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(textRef.current?.clientWidth || 1)
  }, [props.value, refStyle])
  const textStyle = {...refStyle, ...sizerStyle, display: 'inline-block'}
  if (originMinWidth) textStyle.minWidth = originMinWidth
  if (originMaxWidth) textStyle.maxWidth = originMaxWidth
  return <>
    <input ref={inputRef} {...props} style={{...props.style, width: width + 'px'}}/>
    <div ref={textRef} style={textStyle}>
      {props.placeholder}
      <br/>
      {props.value}
    </div>
  </>
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import AutosizeInput from './AutosizeInput'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AutosizeInput
      style={{minWidth: '50px', maxWidth: '100px'}}
      placeholder="Hello"/>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```